# Graphene creates unique ids

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

Here in [relay tutorial](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-relay/) they say:

> Graphene creates globally unique IDs for all objects.
> You may need to copy this value from the results of the first query

Those ids look like this **SW5ncmVkaWVudE5vZGU6MQ==**. And when querying a list of item in **id** field one can see that ids.

How can I get normal (int) ids? Or frontend should convert int ids into string ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom **`relay.Node`** class and override the **`from_global_id(...)`** method

```
from graphene import relay


class MyCustomNode(relay.Node):

    @classmethod
    def from_global_id(cls, global_id):
        return global_id
```